# How to get role in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This is my first Discord bot, so please bear with me if this is dumb!

I've been trying to find a way to get a role, either by name or by ID. Most tutorials that I've found are in line with:

```js
// get role by ID

let myRole = message.guild.roles.get('264410914592129025');

// get role by name

let myRole = message.guild.roles.find((role) => role.name === 'Moderators');
```

Source: https://anidiots.guide/understanding/roles

Yet I keep getting a **`ReferenceError: message is not defined`** error.

Here is my code:

```js
const token = '';

const prefix = '!!';

let role = message.guild.roles.find((role) => role.name === 'among us');
```

My goal is to just actually take the "among us" role and mute the mics for everyone with that role.

```js
//prefix manager
bot.on('message', (message) => {
 //exit and stop if no pref
 if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

 var args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(' ');

 //if !! is used
 switch (args[0]) {
  case 'bing':
   message.reply('bong');
   break;

  case 'HEY':
   message.reply(boulderHello[Math.floor(Math.random() * boulderHello.length)]);
   break;

  case 'muteall':
   role.voice.setMute(true);
   break;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so if something is not defined just define it like so:

```js
const token = '';

const prefix = "!!";


//if it says: can't read property of bot of undefined use client.on instead


bot.on("message", (message) => {
let role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "among us");

//your code here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Message` is not defined by default. It is defined within the `message` event of `Client` as the first parameter.

Here's an example of how to get the role within the `message` event:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    const Role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "among us");

    // You can also get the role by ID like this:
    const Role = message.guild.roles.cache.get("RoleID");
});
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `message` in a `message` event.

```
bot.on(`message`, message => {
  //here you can have your code
});
```

As for finding the role, it's been updated in v12, so you need to do:

```
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get(`id`)
```

And to get it by name:

```
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get(r => r.name === `name`)
```